# .NET C# SHA512 signature encoding does not validate

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, sha512

I need to pass a signature to an API. The instruction specifies the rules:
1) I am given a secret key string
2) I need to concatenate the parameter values passing to the API into a string, separated by "\n", and encode it with UTF8 (such as "firstname\nlastname\n")
3) use SHA512 to encrypt the concatenated string with the secret key
4) convert the encrypted byte array to base64 string

I have my code below, but the API returns an invalid signature error.
What have I done incorrectly? Thank you.

```
  var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretKey");
  HMACSHA512 hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(keyBytes);

  string textToEncrypt = "firstname\nlastname\n";
  byte[] hashText = hmacsha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt));
  string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashText);
```

Changed to SHA512, but still doesn't work....
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA512Managed();
                string secretKey = ConfigurationPropertyProcessor.GetConfigurationPropertyFor("SecretKey");

```
            // Convert the plaintext into bytes.
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);

            // Convert the salt to bytes.
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);

            // Create a new array to hold plain text and salt.
            byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
                new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

            // Copy plain text bytes into the new array.
            for (int i = 0; i < plainTextBytes.Length; i++)
                plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainTextBytes[i];

            // Append salt bytes to the new array.
            for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
                plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainTextBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];



            // Calculate the hash
            byte[] hashBytes = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

            // Convert the outputed hash to a string and return it.
           string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
```

Comment: HMACSHA512 and SHA512 are two different encryptions. Are you sure you were looking for the former?

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code to this, but still got the invalid signature response. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You sould do \\n to accept that String without the magic \n
Can this help you ?